# How to allow anyone to book a meeting in my Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

In an emailing campaign, I want to provide a link to my personal calendar.

People having this link could:

- see my availabilities
- not see the details of my calendar events
- and the main goal → book a meeting whenever is best for them

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You _used_ to be able to set up appointment blocks that people could request, but they removed that functionality some time ago.

Answer (score -1):

A great tool named : calendly.com
:)